# Hot Tub Disconnect Box 220V with a neutral and ground/No neutral in main panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, hot-tub

I am trying to install a portable hot tub in my back yard.  Starting at the tub, I ran two hots and a neutral plus ground back to the 60 amp GFCI in my disconnect box.  Then, I ran the same wires back to my main panel, but my main house panel does not have a neutral bar, what can I do?

Answer (score 5):

Connect the white wire to the bar the other white wires are connected to -- it is not rare for a main service panel to have a combined neutral and ground busbar, as that is the (only!) point where neutral and ground connect.

Answer (score 3):

Neutral and ground are kept separate absolutely everywhere, except one place: the main panel.  Here, it is OK to simply use one bus for both neutral and ground.

You will probably find a lot of whites and a lot of bare wires going to the same bus.  That's the one.

Just for reference, DON'T do this in a sub-panel or you can create a lethal hazard.

Comment: Thank you both for the advice. I did use the ground bar in the main service panel, and the spa is now working great!